# How to group all objects on a slide, which can be grouped, and resize the group?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How do I group all objects (or "shapes"?) on a slide and resize that group?

Subsequently the "big" group should be ungrouped.

My attempt fails with "function expected":

```vb
Sub Group_And_Resize()
    Dim Sld As Slide
    With Sld.Shapes
        With .SelectAll.Group   //Error here
            .Width = 907
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

By manual experimentation, I learned that some objects (or "shapes"?) cannot be added to a group, such as slide numbers which are automatically generated. Is there any possibility to exclude those from the selection?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group the shapes together first and then set the overall width to 907, you can use this code:

```
Sub Group_And_Resize()
    Dim Sld As Slide, a As Variant, i As Integer
    
    Set Sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)  ' your slide
    
    ReDim a(1 To Sld.Shapes.Count)
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        a(i) = Sld.Shapes(i).Name
    Next
    
    Sld.Shapes.Range(a).Group.Width = 907
End Sub
```

If you want to make the width of each of the shapes on the slide = 907, you can use the following code:

```
Sub Group_And_Resize()
    Dim Sld As Slide
    Set Sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)  ' your slide
    Sld.Shapes.Range.Width = 907
End Sub
```

Comment: This has a few problems; 1) it doesn't exclude placeholder shapes, which cannot be grouped. 2) It sets just the width of the final group, not the height, so the shapes within the group are distorted.  See my suggested answer for a different version based on yours.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on Алексей Р's answer but solves a few problems and also is more generic. It allows calling the routine on any slide in the active presentation and setting the width to any desired value. See comments for more details.

```
Sub Test()

    With ActivePresentation
        Call Group_And_Resize(.Slides(1), 200)
    End With

End Sub


Sub Group_And_Resize(Sld As Slide, sngWidth As Single)
    Dim a As Variant, i As Long ' Array indices are longs, not integers
    Dim oGroup As Shape
    
    ' Call NonPlaceholderShapeCount to get number of
    ' shapes that are not placeholders, since placeholders
    ' cannot be grouped. Use that to ReDim the array:
    ReDim a(1 To NonPlaceholderShapeCount(Sld))

    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        ' Again, make sure we don't try to group placeholders
        If Not Sld.Shapes(i).Type = msoPlaceholder Then
            a(i) = Sld.Shapes(i).Name
        End If
    Next
    
    ' Get a reference to the new group
    ' since we need to set several properties on it
    Set oGroup = Sld.Shapes.Range(a).Group
    ' This ensures that the group (and its shapes)
    ' aren't distorted:
    oGroup.LockAspectRatio = True
    ' and finally, set the width
    oGroup.Width = sngWidth
    
End Sub

Function NonPlaceholderShapeCount(Sld As Slide) As Long
' Returns the number of non-placeholder shapes on Sld

    Dim x As Long
    Dim lCount As Long
    
    With Sld
        For x = 1 To .Shapes.Count
            If Not .Shapes(x).Type = msoPlaceholder Then
                lCount = lCount + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With

    NonPlaceholderShapeCount = lCount
    
End Function
```